# Получить данные json через curl

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, curl

Посылаю запрос

```
var url="data?preset=sources_search_phrases"
    $.ajax({
          url:"stat/metrika.php",
          data:"url="+url,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(json){

                    alert(json.query.ids)

          },
```

Обработка на сервере

```
if( $curl = curl_init() ) {

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/".$url); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=".$id."&oauth_token=".$token.""); 
$out = curl_exec($curl);


echo $out;
curl_close($curl);
}
```

Пишет  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined`
если просто вывести json пишет `Request method 'POST' not supported`

На предыдущей версии api yandex все работало,тут нет, это точно правильно `json.query.ids` видимо косяк в формировании `url` для запроса

Comment: а почему вы не выведете в консоль просто `json` и не посмотрите что там реально приходит?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский,object
code
 400
errors
:
Array[1]
0
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array[0] и тд

Comment: вас не смущает `400 error`?....посмотрите в чем именно заключается `400 errors` ...... там в message наверняка написано

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, хм,пишет Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: Все решил проблему,тут была проблема curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=".$id."&oauth_token=".$token."");

Comment: и в чем разница?)

Comment: Это не нужно,ибо через Get работает api